# How to add year in date object which only have month and date

Tags: php, date-difference

```
$duedate = date("Y")."-".$row['due_date'];     //$row['due_date'] = 08-23
$submitdate= $row['sub_date'];     //2016-08-29
$diff = date_diff($duedate,$submitdate);
echo $diff->format("%d days");
```

> Error 1 = date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given.....
>
> Error 2 = Call to a member function format() on boolean in.....

Comment: What u have in $row['due_date'] ???

Comment: try echo $diff->format("%R%a days");

Comment: //$row['due_date'] = 08-23

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

[date_diff function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) requires a DateTime object to be passed into it.

Using the [DateTime::createFromFormat function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) you're able to create a DateTime object from a string, then use it in date_diff.

(This code is not tested and i'm quite new to PHP as well, i hope this helps you!)

```
//Create the date from our records and the current year.
$dueDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date("Y")."-".$row['due_date']); //$row['due_date'] = 08-23
$submitDate= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['sub_date']);     //2016-08-29

$diff = $dueDate->diff($submitDate); //Calculate the difference between the two dates

//Echo it out
echo $diff->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work unless you pass [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to it. Also this can be done using `diff` method on [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. You can check examples in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#refsect1-datetime.diff-examples).

Also, check between what dates you want the difference because it can be both positive and negative 6 days.

```
$duedate = new DateTime(date("Y") . "-" . $row['due_date']);
$submitdate = new DateTime($row['sub_date']);
echo $duedate->diff($submitdate)->format("%R%a days");
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oqZ0D)